# Multiple http request at a time getting slower in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, http, tcp, open-uri

I am trying to maximize the amount of data I can scrape per second with my parser.
The parser sends a get requests with open-uri and parses the response with nokogiri.
I tried put my code in threads and to fork it. But I still cant get it faster.

How can I find out what the bottleneck of my code is?
Why does it take longer to receive the packe when I am making more requests concurrently?
Some of the processes need 3 second and some of them need 30,
How can I find out if the problem is an OS, hardware or a code problem?

Comment: `Why does it take longer to receive the packe when I am making more requests concurrently?` maybe because between the sending and receiving end there's a network with limited bandwidth?  Also not that rfc2616 recommends to limit your concurrent connections to any remote host to 2 (personally I hate misguided users that "powertune" their clients and inundate my server with bazillions of concurrent queries).

Comment: I am doing the requests to different servers and respect the robots.txt!
The modern internet bandwith should be more than enough for the small data that I receive, shouldn't it?

Comment: Merely pointing out a potential next step that would ruin your relationship with the server people :)  If you run the queries from a regular browser, do they also take as long as via code?  Because there are many reasons why a 30-second wait time for a page could be perfectly normal - what I suggest is to 1) not go wild with concurrent requests 2) compare the load times between your code and a browser, or wget or curl.

Comment: No the queries are taking a normal amount of time in my browser. Even when the parser is running. And not all of the queries are taking 30 sec. They take all between 4-30 secs. And if I make more of them, they get slower. But I am not sure why. The bandwitdh should not be the problem